# Block until DataInputStream is available

Tags: java, inputstream, serversocket

I am making an HTTP server as a project for a class that I am attenting ,for a week now I have stuck trying to find a solution .I have a DataInputStream and I need to wait for the client to send me the http request,there can pass hours before that happens since the connection remains  open.This is my code

```
    DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream dos =new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

    while(!socket.isClosed()){
        try{
            /**wait until there are new data in to the stream,if the connection is no more alive then close it*/
            while(dis.available()==0){
                if(alive==false){
                    socket.close();
                    break;
                }
            }

            /*at this point the stream has new data ,or the alive attribute has been set to false */
            if(!socket.isClosed()){
                /*parse the request text */
                Request request=new Request(dis,this);

                /*generate a response based on the request*/
                Response response=new Response(request,this);

                /*send the response back to the client*/
                response.send(dos);

                /*log the details of the communication*/
                Logger.log(toString(request,response,socket));

                /*if the request is bad formatted or it has its Connection header set to close , close the connection after sending the response*/
                if(request.isBadRequest() || !"keep-alive".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getHeader("Connection"))){
                    close();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            break;
        }
    }
```

on the `while(dis.available()==0)` part I am waiting for the stream to have some data,but the problem is that if I have many connections my server starts to get very much cpu time slowing my computer down since it just hangs doing the loop again and again not giving the chance to the cpu to do good scheduling.If the dis.available() was a blocking command then everything would had been perfect.Any workaround?

Comment: This is not how you usually process HTTP requests. Normally, your server socket waits for connection. Once you have a connection, you assume the data is supposed to arrive very soon, and if they don't come within a set timeout (not more than a minute, usually), then you close the connection.

Comment: @RealSkeptic ,but what if the first request has its connection header set to keep-alive ?,shouldn't I keep the connection alive and wait until the client sends the next request?

Comment: There is also an expiry timeout for keepalives. In real servers, it's adjustable. In Apache, for example, the default is 5 seconds, and they warn you that increasing it too much affects performance. The idea of keepalive is to allow the user to avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection, it is not meant to be a permanent, endless connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InputStreams` *already* block in the read methods while no data is available.

You don't need a single one of these `available()` calls or loops around them.

You should also note that `Socket.isClosed()` only returns true if *you* have closed the socket. It doesn't tell whether the peer has closed the connection.

Comment: I was first using the readLine() method of the InputDataStream and this method instead of blocking was returning null when there where not any data .I changed it to read()...now I just have to find a way to make it look elegant(if you see my code above)

Comment: `readLine()` returns null *at end of stream.* Not 'when there is not any data'. If you got null, the peer had disconnected.